# Toggling booleans with javascript for a dark mode feature

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set up a dark mode. This logic doesn't quite work.

I have re-arranged the variables multiple times. I can't quite figure it out.

```
var isDarkMode = false;
var darkModeToggle = false;


function toggleDarkMode(){
  if (isDarkMode === false && darkModeToggle === false){
    isDarkMode = true;
    setDarkMode();

  }

  if (isDarkMode === true && darkModeToggle === true){
    isDarkMode = false; 
    setDarkMode();

    darkModeToggle = false;

  }

  darkModeToggle = true;


}

function setDarkMode(){
    if (isDarkMode === true){
  //Change to dark
  }


  if (isDarkMode === false){
//Change to light
  }


}
```

I have the rest of the functionality done. I think I am missing some easy, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: `toggleDarkMode()` is as easy as `isDarkMode = !isDarkMode; setDarkMode();` - there is no reason to test value in that function.

Comment: Can you elaborate ab it more please?

Comment: I have elaborated in my answer. let me know if you have questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overcomplicated things a bit. I don't know the reason for the `darkModeToggle` variable so I've excluded it from my solution.

`toggleDarkMode()` is as easy as

`isDarkMode = !isDarkMode; 
 setDarkMode();`

- there is no reason to test value in that function as you'll see below.

```js
var isDarkMode = false;

function toggleDarkMode() {
  isDarkMode = !isDarkMode;
  setDarkMode();
}

function setDarkMode() {
  if (isDarkMode) {
    console.log("Change to dark");
  } else {
    console.log("Change to light");
  }
}

toggleDarkMode();
toggleDarkMode();
toggleDarkMode();
toggleDarkMode();
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. And thank you for giving me that tip.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two variables. Just keep a single variable to track current mode. Have a look at following working example:

```js
var isDarkMode = false;

function toggleDarkMode(){
    var $el = document.getElementById("test");
    if (!isDarkMode){
      //Change to dark
      $el.style.background = "black";
      $el.style.color = "white";
    } else {
      //Change to light
      $el.style.background = "white";
      $el.style.color = "black";
    }
    isDarkMode = !isDarkMode;    
}
```

```css
#test {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p id ="test"> Test Paragraph </p>
<button onclick = "toggleDarkMode()"> Toggle Dark Mode </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

- As an example we'll say dark mode involves the `<main>` element having the class `.dark`.
- Declare `let mode = false` outside your toggle function.
- Place this ternary control statement in your toggle function:

  ```
  /* pseudo-code:*/ mode = condition........... if.true...else..false
  /* real code..:*/ mode = main.matches('.dark') ? true    :    false;
  ```

  *"If main has class `.dark` then `mode` is `true` else its `false`"*

Click anywhere in demo to toggle dark mode.

```js
let mode = false;
const main = document.querySelector('main');
main.onclick = toggleMode;

function toggleMode(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('main')) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('dark');
    mode = main.matches('.dark') ? true : false;
    console.log(mode);
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  font: 700 small-caps 3vw/1.2 Taholma;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #dad;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.dark {
  color: #fc0;
  background: #000;
}

h1::before {
  content: 'Default ';
}

.dark h1::before {
  content: 'Dark ';
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Mode</h1>
</main>
```